# Sentence classification(SST2 data) with BertForSequenceClassification of huggingface

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I’m working on sentence classification with pretrained BERT.
I used `BertForSequenceClassification` class but it doesn’t look being trained.
Maybe I'm getting wrong output but I can't figure out what is the right output.
Can someone let me know what’s wrong with this code?

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.optim import AdamW
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torchtext.datasets import SST2
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, BertForSequenceClassification

LR = 0.0005
EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 128

device = torch.device("cuda:" + "0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
base_model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
max_input_length = 128


model = base_model.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=LR)

train_datapipe = SST2(split="train")
valid_datapipe = SST2(split="dev")

def collate_batch(batch):
    ids, types, masks, label_list = [], [], [], []
    for text, label in batch:
        tokenized = tokenizer(text,
                              padding="max_length", max_length=max_input_length,
                              truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        ids.append(tokenized['input_ids'])
        types.append(tokenized['token_type_ids'])
        masks.append(tokenized['attention_mask'])
        label_list.append(label)

    input_data = {
        "input_ids": torch.squeeze(torch.stack(ids)).to(device),
        "token_type_ids": torch.squeeze(torch.stack(types)).to(device),
        "attention_mask": torch.squeeze(torch.stack(masks)).to(device)
    }
    label_list = torch.tensor(label_list, dtype=torch.int64)
    return input_data, label_list


train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_datapipe, shuffle=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, collate_fn=collate_batch)
valid_dataloader = DataLoader(valid_datapipe, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, collate_fn=collate_batch)

# print("total instances: ", len(train_dataloader))
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    train_loss = []
    all_labels = []
    all_outs = []

    for i, (input_data, label) in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
        model.zero_grad()
        output = model(**input_data).logits
        label = label.to(device)
        loss = criterion(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```